# Highlight positions after the EOL character

Tags: vim

I am, currently, attempting to replicate the vim feature 'colorcolumn'. In addition to replicating 'colorcolumn', I have ideas that would require replicating 'cursorcolumn' and 'cursorline'. However, all my attempts to match a specific column are dependent on a character occupying that specific column.

To put it another way, I cannot come up with a way to match any position after the EOL ('$') character.

For instance, the following will only highlight column 25 if a character occupies that position. This is, similarly, true for `:match`, `match()`, `matchadd()`, and `matchaddpos()`.

```
:highlight CC2 ctermbg=green
:syntax match CC2 /\%25v./
```

I don't want to focus too much on a particular idea, but my present idea for 'colorcolumn' is to have several different columns (which is easy enough; `:set cc=10,20,30`), but each column would have it's own background color. Say, green at column 80, yellow at 100, and red at 120.

Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible, since match works only on the buffer content, so if there is no content, the column can't be matched.

BTW: That is one reason, why the 'colorcolumn' option has been implemented.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. After posing this question, I had started to come to this conclusion after pouring through the `:help` documentation, but I was hopeful that there might be some feature that I was unaware of. I suppose that I'll have to request for this feature upstream. Thanks, again.

Comment: That will require major changes to the screen.c module. I don't think this is going to happen soon.